# Use arrayList to display in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, textarea, containers

I want to be able to display all items in an arrayList in a JTextArea. This is the code I have but it does not work.

```
public void display()
{
    JPanel display = new JPanel();
    display.setVisible(true);
    JTextArea a;

    for (Shape ashape : alist)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(ashape.toString());
        a = new JTextArea(ashape.toString()); 
        display.add(a);
    }

    Container content = getContentPane(); 
    content.add(display);
}
```

Comment: If am right, it will be displayed only one text area, because its simply overriding the one textarea with another, as the size and position is same for all text area, just set position for JTextArea after its created.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
JTextArea a;
```

inside for loop, like so:

```
for (Shape ashape : alist) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(ashape.toString());

        //initialise a here 
        JTextArea a = new JTextArea(ashape.toString()); 
        display.add(a);
    }

    Container content = getContentPane(); 
    content.add(display);
}
```

Also, what does it mean "it doesn't work" in your program?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. To start with, your example code is creating a new `JTextArea` for each `Shape`, but it is only ever adding the last to the UI.

Assuming you want to display all the information in a single text area, you could simply use `JTextArea#append`, for example

```
JTextArea a = new JTextArea();

for (Shape ashape : a list)
{
    System.out.println(ashape.toString());
    a.append(ashape.toString() + "\n")
}

Container content = getContentPane(); 
content.add(display);
```

Ps- you may want to wrap the text area within a `JScrollPane` so it can overflow